# Token contains the spacial character "/" and I need to store string as it is due to its usage

Tags: java, android, json, string

I am having a Token which has special characters and they need to be stored inside a string.

> eg. - abcdefgsd/\sddsddsdedasad

string converts this into **abcdefgsd=**

what I want is to store the whole string and still be used frequently?

Comment: what is the issue? please explain what you want with this string? if you want to store whole string then store it? do u want to remove special character from your string or anything else ?

Comment: I want to store the characters as it is but by printing command it removes the spacial character.

Comment: can you show your code? where you use print statement

Comment: String can easily store any special character in it. Can you share your code?

Comment: i am having "/" "\" in my string

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be is, in the string `abcdefgsd/\sddsddsdedasad` , backslash `\` will be recognized as an illegal escape character by the compiler. To avoid this you may need to add an extra backward slash to the string like below.

```
abcdefgsd/\\sddsddsdedasad
```